# Problem with delete syntax in SQL - Error Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT NumeroReloj, Badgenumber, Name, lastname, DEFAULTDEPTID
FROM [PBS].[dbo].[CAT_Empleados]
RIGHT JOIN [AccessControl].[dbo].[USERINFO]
ON [PBS].[dbo].[CAT_Empleados].[NumeroReloj] = [AccessControl].[dbo].[USERINFO].[Badgenumber] COLLATE Chinese_PRC_CI_AS
WHERE [AccessControl].[dbo].[USERINFO].[Badgenumber] COLLATE Chinese_PRC_CI_AS NOT IN (SELECT [NumeroReloj] FROM [PBS].[dbo].[CAT_Empleados])
```

There are 2 data bases, and 2 tables with different names.

With that query I get some users who are in table [AccessControl].[dbo].[USERINFO] but they are not in table [PBS].[dbo].[CAT_Empleados].

The Employee# column for [AccessControl].[dbo].[USERINFO] is named 'Badgenumber', and the Employee# column for [PBS].[dbo].[CAT_Empleados] is named 'NumeroReloj' (thats how match both results).

Well, that query is working fine, and now I want to delete in [AccessControl].[dbo].[USERINFO] the same results that I get in that Select query. I have tried by:

```
DELETE 
FROM [AccessControl].[dbo].[USERINFO] 
WHERE [AccessControl].[dbo].[USERINFO].[Badgenumber] IN (SELECT * FROM [PBS].[dbo].[CAT_Empleados] RIGHT JOIN [AccessControl].[dbo].[USERINFO] ON [PBS].[dbo].[CAT_Empleados].[NumeroReloj] = [AccessControl].[dbo].[USERINFO].[Badgenumber] COLLATE Chinese_PRC_CI_AS WHERE [AccessControl].[dbo].[USERINFO].[Badgenumber] COLLATE Chinese_PRC_CI_AS NOT IN (SELECT [NumeroReloj] FROM [PBS].[dbo].[CAT_Empleados])
```

But I'm getting this error message:

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Only one expression can be
>   specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with
>   EXISTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that your delete statement, you are asking to delete only employees with a badgenumber in a sub query which returns multiple fields, as denoted by "*". So SQL doesn't know what you want badgenumber to compare to.

Change the "*" in your subquery to match 1 field, that is the field you want to compare with the badgenumber.

Comment: Thank yhou alex067, it works. I just changed * for Badgenumber.